# CSS Dropdown Glitchy

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

The dropdown works when you rollover the top buttons but when you try to move down to the dropdown menu it disappears.

http://vistaazulresort.com/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? You should start by adding some code rather than just a link to your site. You will get a much more positive and helpful response from the community if you provide the information, rather than make us search for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that your using hover to make the dropdown appear. If a user doesn't hover over the menu item just right, the dropdown won't show/disappear. Not to mention it won't work on most mobile devices.

The solution would be to use jQuery, especially since you are already having jQuery(1.8.3) being loaded.

I won't write the whole menu for you because you need to learn. However, I'll give you enough to get you started. Here are the important aspects...

```
.dropdown li ul {
    display:none;
}
.show-dropdown li ul {
    display:block;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#menu-top").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("dropdown show-dropdown");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Remove the link tags from the menu items with the dropdowns.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRkBM/